# Cannot find my app in developers.facebook.com/apps although it does exist

Tags: facebook

about 6 months ago i created an app to let users of my site login through facebook.
the app is working fine and my users are actually logging in through facebook.

here are the details of the app

App ID: 251611944876980 
App Name: SFINZ

now, when i login to my fan page
www.facebook.com/sfinz
with my username: social at sfinz.me
if i try to go to developers.facebook.com/apps i get redirected to www.facebook.com/sfinz

there is no way for me to find this app which i need to edit!

can anyone tell me what happened?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you open https://developers.facebook.com/apps/251611944876980 ? This should be the page to edit the app. If you cannot access the app then maybe you used some other account to create this app.

Comment: nope! it redirects me to the fan page... i am pretty sure i have created it with the account i have... is there any way to know which account created the app?

Comment: is it possible that has something to do with the username i used to create it? something weird with some settings? i am using social at sfinz dot me
any help is appreciated, really!

Comment: It looks like your user doesn't have access to the application. Could you set up a new Facebook application for the same thing and use that one instead?